# -[GAITrackerImpl setAllowIDFACollection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

### The Crash

In order to track demographics in our app, I've added the `allowIDFACollection = YES` line recommended by Google. As soon as I run it without debug, though, I get the unrecognized selector crash on the 2nd line below:

```
gGoogleTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-99999999-9"];
gGoogleTracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

Crash:
`-[GAITrackerImpl setAllowIDFACollection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170286d10`

### Setup

As far as I can tell, GAI is correctly integrated, but I must be missing something because otherwise it shouldn't crash! Here are all the relevant details I could think of:

The project includes both `AdSupport.framework` and both of the Google Analytics binaries:

[image: AdSupport.framework]
[image: Google Analytics Folder]

The Google Analytics files are stored in Activehours/frameworks:

[image: Library Search Paths]

Both `libAdIdAccess.a` and `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` are linked into the binary, as is the AdSupport framework (not shown):

[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

Other Linker flags looks like this, with `-ObjC` included:

[image: Other Linker Flags]

Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong here? Having same issue.

Comment: No. It wasn't critical to our project, so I just commented it out for the time being in order to get a build out the door. :(

Comment: I think i found a solution `[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] setAllowIDFACollection:YES];`

Comment: Thanks, @JeffN. That _still_ gives me `unrecognized selector sent to instance`, sadly. Also, I'm unclear what the ramifications would be of setting IDFA collection on the default tracker when we're using a tracker with a custom tracking ID for everything else. Glad it's working for you, though!

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to solve this issue. You can write

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker setAllowIDFACollection:YES];
```

or

```
id <GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

Comment: I'm no longer working on the project in question, but if you read the comments, this solution still caused a crash.

Comment: this code is a bit different than the others, i implemented this 2 days ago and it works fine, in future if you implement it, try this exact code once, or you can check it now by making a demo code, its upto you

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I meant to write, "still caused a crash in our project." As it stands, this entire question is probably just noise at this point since I'm no longer at the company in question. Appreciate the feedback regardless! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured where is the problem.

`GAI *gGoogleTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-99999999-9"];`

you should not call that in one line. Replace that line with next two:

`GAI *gGoogleTracker = [GAI sharedInstance];
[gGoogleTracker trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-99999999-9"];`

that's how it's described in the gide and it will work correctly